# No output from Python subprocess

Tags: python, windows, shell, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm using Python 3.5.1 and Windows 10. I can't get `subprocess` to put output to the screen. So let's start with something simple:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.run('echo hi', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

When I run my python module, I want to it to print 'hi' in the Python Shell. The script runs and does not return an error, but it prints nothing to the screen.

I have also tried many different flavors of `subprocess` (i.e. `Popen`), but still no luck. I have a feeling this has something to do with the way my Windows/Python environment is setup, but I don't really know where to start. Thoughts?

---

### Update

So I now understand that my original code sample should not have put anything on the screen; however, when I run

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.run('echo hi', shell=True)
```

I get no output. When I run:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.run('echo hi', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p.stdout)
```

I do get output. Why did the first example not work?

Comment: The reason the output is not going to the screen is that you've told `subprocess` to route standard output to a pipe instead of to the screen.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the pipe then. According to the docs, subprocess.pipe is a "Special value that can be used as the stdin, stdout or stderr argument to Popen and indicates that a pipe to the standard stream should be opened." So where is the output being piped to?

Comment: @David The purpose of using `PIPE` is so that you can communicate with the process via python *file-like* objects, and also so use different pipes for different processes.  For instance, to prevent multiple processes from all writing to stdout at the same time.  The pipes are created on the `.stdin`, `.stdout`, and `.stderr` attributes on the subprocess object

Comment: So when I run the process without the pipe argument, the output is going to the normal stdout? Which is obviously not the screen in my setup?

Comment: Wait is the stdout in this case the windows command shell as opposed to the python shell? Which is why I don't see anything

Comment: Unless you're doing something to tell it otherwise, python should be using the stdout of the shell it's running in.

Comment: Well I can't explain Python's behavior then. Regardless, the PIPE approach is working. Thank you!

Comment: `stdout` is (on Windows) a file handle.  In a console process it "points" to the console, just as a different file handle might "point" to a conventional file.  By default, when you create a new process from a Windows console the `stdout` is copied to the new process.  The console is shared  by the new process as well.  Both these actions can be overridden.  No shell need be involved!  On Windows a console does not need a shell.  `python.exe` is a console program, it depends how it is launched as to which console is used.

Answer (score 7):

It's not printing to the screen because you're redirecting the output to a `PIPE`.  Remove the pipe argument and the output will go to the normal `stdout`

You can use `subprocess.call` also.

```
subprocess.call('echo hi', shell=True)
```

If you want to pipe the output, you should use `Popen` instead

```
process = subprocess.Popen('echo hi', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print process.stdout.read()
```

If you want to decode the result as UTF-8 format, just add `.decode('UTF-8')`

```
process.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: When I remove the pipe argument and run my code again, I get no output to the screen. Using your script with Popen, I do get output. Where is it getting piped to? And why doesn't it print to the screen if I remove the pipe argument?

Comment: No it doesn't. I'm also using Python 3.5, and I believe subprocess.call is just a legacy feature that calls run anyway?

Comment: @David, in the question you say want it to output to "Python Shell". Are you referring to IDLE? If so, you need to first attach pythonw.exe to a console. Otherwise Windows creates a console automatically, which gets destroyed as soon as cmd.exe exits since no other process is attached to the console. The following allocates and attaches to a console: `import ctypes; ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32').AllocConsole()`.